# Python pandas: Get first values of group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a list of recorded diagnoses like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "DiagnosisTime": ["2017-01-01 08:23:00", "2017-01-01 08:23:00", "2017-01-01 08:23:03", "2017-01-01 08:27:00", "2019-12-31 20:19:39", "2019-12-31 20:19:39"],
    "ID": [1,1,1,1,2,2]
})
```

[image]

There are multiple subjects that can be identified by an `ID`. For each subject there may be one or more diagnosis. Each diagnosis may be comprised of multiple entries (as multiple things are recoreded (not in this example)).

The individual diagnoses (with multiple rows) can (to some extend) be identified by the `DiagnosisTime`. However, sometimes there is a little delay during the writing of data for one diagnosis so that I want to allow a small tolerance of a few seconds when grouping by `DiagnosisTime`.

In this example I want a result as follows:

[image]

There are two diagnoses for `ID` 1: rows 0, 1, 2 and row 3. Note the slightly different `DiagnosisTime` in row 2 compared to 0 and 1. `ID` 2 is comprised of 1 diagnosis comprised of rows 4 and 5.

For each `ID` I want to set the counter back to 1 (or 0 if thats easier).

This is how far I've come:

```
df["DiagnosisTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DiagnosisTime"])
df["diagnosis_number"] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='5S', key="DiagnosisTime"), 'ID']).ngroup()
```

[image]

I think I successfully identified diagnoses within one `ID` (not entirely sure about the Grouper), but I don't know how to reset the counter.

If that is not possible I would also be satisfied with a function which returns all records of one `ID` that have the lowest `diagnosis_number` within that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add lambda function with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df["diagnosis_number"] = (df.groupby('ID')['diagnosis_number']
                             .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1)
print (df)
        DiagnosisTime  ID  diagnosis_number
0 2017-01-01 08:23:00   1                 1
1 2017-01-01 08:23:00   1                 1
2 2017-01-01 08:23:03   1                 1
3 2017-01-01 08:27:00   1                 2
4 2019-12-31 20:19:39   2                 1
5 2019-12-31 20:19:39   2                 1
```

Comment: Great, that works! It seems to take up quite some time when running with larger data, but I think I can afford. Thanks!